# Why won't my Angular form react to validating changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following [form](http://jsbin.com/cerigodala/edit?html,css,js,output). I added the reaction to submit action `ng-submit="signupForm()"` and handle like the following:

```
controller('signupController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.signupForm = function () {
        if (!$scope.signup_form.$valid) {
            $scope.signup_form.submitted = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Each error block check that flag and makes decision whether to be shown or not:

```
<div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.name.$dirty && signup_form.name.$invalid && signup_form.submitted">....</div>
```

The check itself is `signup_form.submitted`.
But unfortunately when I submit the form these error blocks are not shown.

Comment: try using built in `signup_form.$submitted`.

Comment: Doesn't work too :(